# Reflection between two mirrors?

Tags: optics, speed-of-light, reflection

If I put my hand between two perfectly aligned mirrors and then remove it will the images continue to reflect for a few nanoseconds?

If yes then will the images be of a combination of the front and back of my hand or will a clear image of both appear to occilate from one mirror to the other?

In other words will the palm of my hand appear at least once on the mirror that faces the back of my hand?

Comment: It would be like the sound of a falling tree with no one to hear. Ionized gas in a LASER when power is cut.

Answer (score 1):

> If I put my hand between two perfectly aligned mirrors and then remove
>   it will the images continue to reflect for a few nanoseconds?

It is true that a few nanoseconds correspond to a few meters: in such a short time, rays may still be between the two mirrors. But there are no "images" of your hand, unless you use an imaging system such as lenses or curved mirrors.

> If yes then will the images be of a combination of the front and back
>   of my hand or will a clear image of both appear to occilate from one
>   mirror to the other?

You have a misconception of what an "image" is. Let's suppose you make images using curved mirrors. These images will be formed at some specific location between the two mirrors, but you can't see them unless you put a screen or something that sends the rays to your eyes. If you do so, you will remove the rays from the system, so no more light in there.

But ok, we don't need to see images, just "know" they are in there. Theoretically you can keep rays an infinite time with perfect mirrors. In that case, you will have an image of your palm somewhere and an image of the back of your hand somewhere else. You may be able to have them at the same place, but I don't see the point.

> In other words will the palm of my hand appear at least once on the
>   mirror that faces the back of my hand?

Again, you can keep rays a long time between the two mirrors, even if your hand is gone. But no image will "appear" to your eyes unless you extract the rays.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that you need curved mirrors and that a clear image would not appear once and be seen by a fast enough camera or eye. This is because I think of how a periscope can transfer an image from one mirror to another mirror.

Comment: An image has to be formed by something like lenses (like in a camera or your eyes) or curved mirrors. Flat mirrors only reflect light, same for periscopes. Overall your question does not make much sense to me. We may have different understanding of what an "image" is.

Comment: ok, when I look at myself in the mirror I see what I call an image. Are you saying it is not an image unless a lense is involved?

Comment: Yes. The lens involved is your eye. Your eye receives the light emitted by yourself and reflected by the mirror. It makes an image on your retina. If you have light bouncing between mirrors, it will never reach your eye or a camera or something that makes an image.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question...I think there are two complications to this: 1.) Image formation requires the light to be scattered on the surface/surface layers of your hand, which will significantly decrease the intensity of light remaining between the mirrors. 2.) Light is fast, so your hand has to move very fast as well. Even for large distances between the mirrors, the image (that could be produced e.g. using a lens) will most probably be blurred, since the hand will be in motion for a significant time period. Moreover, I imagine that one could observe chromatic effects due to the ultra-fast "chopping" of the beam.